# Push sub document onto array and update, AND return that created sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to push a document onto an array of sub documents on an existing document. So I do:

```
Person.findByIdAndUpdateQ(req.params.id, { $push: {"minders": minder} }, {safe: true, upsert: true})
.then(function(updatedPerson) { ... });
```

I want access to the `created` minder in `minders`. The way I've done it is as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711136/in-mongoose-how-do-i-push-a-subdocument-onto-an-array-of-a-saved-objects-and-the), **but is there a nicer way**

```
Person.findById(req.params.id, function(err, person) {
  var responseIndex = person.minders.push(minder) - 1;
  person.save(function(saveErr, savedMinder) {
    return res.json(201, savedMinder.minders[responseIndex]);
  })
})
```